# horizontal division symbol error

Tags: document-classes, article

I've been trying to prove an entity but I'm unable to represent this entity with a horizontal division bar in Latex. The best I've got till now is \left(\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right) but this puts useless brackets around the proposition. When I compile without the braces, I get **Missing Delimiter** error. Can anyone please help me out here?

Comment: Perhaps like this? `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ \end{document}`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been solved in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try `\left.`  and `\right.` as "invisible" braces, 
but I don't see why you would need them here.

`$\frac{n(n-1)}{2} $` should work perfectly fine.